# Java regex memory variables

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if Regex in Java has memory variables like they do in perl. If so, how are they used.

Comment: No, Java only has numbered capture groups, not named ones.  JDK7 will have named ones, but only those corresponding to Perl’s `%+` hash, not those from `%-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean back references, then yes Java has this. You can refer to a capturing group inside a regular expression using the notation `\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second, etc. Note that inside a string literal the backslashes must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

The Java `java.util.regex.Pattern` class supports backreferences using the `\n` syntax.

See [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.